# Iframe content not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, button, iframe

I am trying to create an iframe in which the content changes based on a button click. However the iframe is not displaying any content. Could someone take a look at my code and explain why.

```
<script>
int i = 0;
var array= ["news1.html","news2.html","news3.html"];   
    function setURL(){ 
        if (i<2) {
           i = i+1;
                 }
        else{
           i=0;
            };
        document.getElementById("iframe").src = array[i];

                 }
</script>

<iframe id="iframe" style="float:right;" width="770" height="360"></iframe>

<button type="button" onclick="setURL()" style="float:right;"> Next </button>
```

I know it's not the best code in the world but as far as I can tell it should work so I was hoping for a hand with it please?

Comment: I think thr is a typo case - `int i = 0;` should be `var i = 0;`

Comment: And next time, check the JS console.

Comment: It was, thank you! And I should have checked the console, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your variable declaration from:

```
int i = 0;
```

to:

```
var i = 0;
```

Everything worked once i changed that.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly! I should have seen it but I don't have any experience in javascript. Thanks again!